# Why do i get an error when trying class code like this? Im beginner sorry

Tags: c++, codeblocks

For some reason i cant get this code to run? Everyone else can make it run.. i could a few months ago but now im just getting error. The error reads as follows error:

> 'Animals::name' should be initialized in the member initialization list -Werror=effc++

Im actually pissed of lol... im a beginner too and i just want to practice.

I've tried making different class code examples but noone them works whenever i include string in it or something different than just a simple cout function.

It doesn't work it just gives me the error i typed in above even tho the code should work fine... i cant practice because of this.

```
class Animals{`public:`string name;`};`
```

Then the rest is class object name etc for example Animals dog then dog.name "name" and then cout.

I expect the code to output Caow and Fatty.
I mean it's just a simple code because im trying to learn but it just wont work because of this random weird annoying error!!! I've been looking allover the internet to find a solution but i can't find any.

Comment: Are the backticks some sort of artifact introduced when pasting the line up here?

Comment: use this http://wandbox.org/ to provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Apparently you have `-Werror` flag on, which treats all warnings as errors, and you have a warning which tells you what you're doing is inefficient. Please show us the constructor of your class, the problem should be right there.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1546f9dd86b471a1). But that error is not random or weird. You explicitly told the compiler you want warnings about not following advice from effective c++ and that you want those warnings be treated as an error. Maybe don't do that.

Comment: Using `-Werror` causes the compilation to terminate when the compiler wishes to issue a warning.   The warning you're getting (which is being treated as an error) is one of those enabled by the `=effc++`.   `-Werror=effc++` is being set by you .... don't set it.

Comment: I think using `-Werror` as long as possible is a good habit and you should try to fix the warning and not disable it. It was a necessary flag at our university and is the default in new projects in our company.

Comment: Ah lol i just figured out how to disable this warning thing.... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I expect your code to look something like that

```
#include <string>

class Animal {
public:
    Animal(std::string aName) {
        name = aName;
    }
    std::string name;
};

int main() {
    Animal a("a");
    return 0;
}
```

You are initializing your string in the body of the constructor. But you should use the initialization list of the constructor:

```
#include <string>

class Animal {
public:
    Animal(std::string aName): name(aName) {
    }
    std::string name;
};

int main() {
    Animal a("a");
    return 0;
}
```